# Where condition in Slick

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

How to achieve the equivalent in Slick?

```
select * from table1 where col1 = 1 AND (col2 = 2 or col3 = 3)
```

This doesn't work:

```
val action = table.filter(_.col1 === 1 && (_.col2 === 2 || _.col3 === 3)).result
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the short hand in this case.  Try this:

```
 val action = table.filter( x => x.col1 == 1 && (x.col2 == 2 || x.col3 == 3)).result
```